# Easy customizable image gallery with comments

Tags: php, database, image, gallery, customization

Can someone tell me a image gallery plugin with comments which can be customized via CSS? 
I need opinions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options. For a detailed list with comparisions, see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_gallery_software

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gallery http://www.tinywebgallery.com/

Powerful and no need to have a database to run it.